# Selenium Webdriver Unable To Select The DropDown Value

Tags: java, selenium, dropdown

I am trying to select a value displayed Upon expanding A dropdown for which the DOM is

```
<a class="mcacAnchor">
<span style="padding:0 4px;float:left;width:8em;">L</span>
<div style="clear: both;"/>
</a>
```

Now, the dropdown gets Expanded it clicks  "L" but that does not go(value L) into the field containing the dropdown.

Surprisingly the execution moves further.

I have tried Xpath,contains text but nothing seems to work.

The code to handle it:

```
WebElement Icon=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='FlatID']/..//span"));
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Icon);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'L')]")).click();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `clicks "L" but that does not go(value L)`? Can you sum up the Manual Steps you are trying to Automate along with the `HTML` of the `dropdown`?

Comment: It means When I click On Drop down icon/symbol, A drop down containing only one value "L" is displayed.And my requirement is to click on the visible element L after which the drop down disappears and the field will contain the value L.

Comment: Can you show us some more outerHTML of the span tag?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to perform `click()` operation on the same object, which is `L`.

> I am trying to select a value displayed Upon expanding A dropdown

You probably should perform click on drop-down first

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement("//a[@class='mcacAnchor']")
```

> Now, the dropdown gets Expanded it clicks "L" but that does not go(value L) into the field containing the dropdown.

Now, dropdown is Expanded and you can perform `click()` operation on `L` element.

```
WebElement lElement = dropdown.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'L')]"));
lElement.click();
```

In above line, we are not using `driver` to find an element but `dropdown` as it will reduce scope of our `findElement` method to this particular `dropdown`. 
`The .//` in xpath means `perform search reduced to provided scope`.

However, depends on your application, Selenium might perform `click` on non-visible `L` element, because it might work faster than the browser. It will open the dropdown but it will not wait until dropdown is displayed.

Such wait can be implemented using `WebDriverWait`.

Example for your code (and final solution):

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement("//a[@class='mcacAnchor']")
WebElement lElement = dropdown.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'L')]"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); //it will wait 10 seconds for desired condition
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visiblityOf(lElement));
lElement.click();
```

Comment: Thanks Rafal but I had implemented the wait condition before also.

Comment: Please, update your question. Add new code, tell us what you have tried and what failed after my answer. Maybe we will be able to help you.